# корректное чтение данных при использовании inotify.

Tags: linux, c

При работе с inotify в linux возник следующий параноидальный вопрос. Как известно при получении программой сигнала системный вызов read, прерывает своё выполнение и либо возвращает -1 и выставляет errno, что системный вызов был прерван сигналом и ничего мы получить не успели, либо же возвращает количество прочитанных байт. Для чтения событий, связанных с набором файлов, за которыми мы следим с помощью inotify как раз используется read.
Минимальный размер буфера для возникшего события равен

```
sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1
```

Вопрос: если сигнал поступит в тот момент, когда мы читаем данные о событии, то считаем мы не все данные. И выполнив следующие действия:

```
struct inotify_event *pevent = (struct inotify_event *) buffer;
```

будем иметь указатель на невалидные данные. К тому же (исключительно ИМХО), скорее всего при следующем чтении, данные будут получены с того места где остановились при предыдущем чтении, и в результате текущего чтения опять будут получены невалидные данные. В теории такая ситуация возможна. Но стоит ли навешивать различные проверки на чтение из дескриптора, получающего события? Или если я полностью ошибаюсь в своих рассуждениях прошу поправить. Из всех примеров по работе с inotify, никто до такой паранойи не дошел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько помню, если `read(fd, buf, size)` прерван сигналом, то никакие данные в буфер ядром не переносились. В этом смысле `read` атомарен.

Другой момент (явного описания я в манах не нашел, но что происходит на самом деле экспериментально проверил) может быть интересней.

Вопрос в том, вернет ли повторно `select/poll/epoll` *readable* для inotify дескриптора, если мы прочли только часть уже доступных events?

Ответ -- да, еще не прочитанные, но явно наступившие и находящиеся в очереди  events тут же вызывают срабатывание по крайней мере `poll` (впрочем, я уверен, что `select` и `epoll` сработают так же).

Т.е. тут тоже все ОК и можно не опасаться, что прочитав одним `read` не все (мы же можем узнать их количество лишь полностью проанализировав считанные в буфер данные, поскольку размер `struct inotify_event` не константа (зависит от поля `len` в этой структуре)) уже помещенные о очередь events мы что-то потеряем.

(Хотя, в [man inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) пишут:

> Note  that  the event queue can overflow.  In this case, events are
>   lost.  Robust applica‐    tions should handle the possibility of lost
>   events gracefully.  For  example,  it  may  be    necessary  to 
>   rebuild  part  or  all of the application cache.  (One simple, but
>   possibly    expensive, approach is to close the inotify file
>   descriptor, empty the cache, create a new    inotify  file 
>   descriptor, and then re-create watches and cache entries for the
>   objects to    be monitored.))

От этого, конечно, не спасает, но приободряет, что

> The  FIONREAD  ioctl(2) returns the number of bytes available to
>   read from an inotify file    descriptor.

Возвращаясь к исходному вопросу еще раз, можно сказать, что если `read()` прочел данные (вернул не -1), то мы и не узнаем, что приходил сигнал. Если вернул -1 и `EINTR`, то ничего из очереди не пропало и в буфер не попало.

А нормально у нас `len = read(fd, buf, size)` вернет `len` не больше `size` и в буфере будет одна или более структур, каждая размером `sz = sizeof *str + str->len` (`str` это `struct inotify_event *`).

Узнать сколько именно можно только в цикле, сдвигаясь на каждом шаге на `sz`.

Comment: В man inotify(7) сказано следующее: Each successful read(2) returns a buffer containing one or more of the following structures. То есть наш буфер будет заполнен в зависимости от его размера и количества считанных структур. А select readable возвращает 100 процентов, по крайней мере в Debian.

Comment: Про read точно ничего сказать не могу, поэтому этот вопрос здесь и есть, просто судя по man read: **If a read() is interrupted by a signal before it reads any data, it shall return -1 with errno set to [EINTR].
If a read() is interrupted by a signal after it has successfully read some data, it shall return the number of bytes read.**

Answer (score 1):

функция read при чтении событий возвращает одно или несколько событий. Поэтому вариант, что данные окажутся невалидными исключается.